# How does such issue is possible: an integer is being of non-numeric?

Tags: php

```
$id=intval(array['id']);
echo ($id+1);

gettype($id) : integer
gettype($id+1) : integer

PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /var/www/html/xxxx on line xxx
```

How does is possible that integer is non-numeric?

// PHP 7.3

Comment: What is `array['id']` ? Isn't a string?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov Looks like no, SQL table's raw's value in this column is integer.

Comment: You didn't understand me. If that's your code you have an error. Maybe you should call `$array['id']` ?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov ... It has own $name and is being called with it, I just simplified it here.

Comment: the error is coming from your echo?

Comment: Post dump of that variable and `on line xxx`. X = ?

Comment: @pr1nc3 yes, correct

Comment: @D.Dimitrov string(3) "107" and with intval() - int(107)

Comment: Interesting, judging by [Official docs](http://php.net/manua/en/function.intval.php) `intval()` should always return a number, it has no other return values. The posted code actually has an `Parse error` because of `array['id']` which should be `$array['id']`

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin indeed. that's why I was wondered with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "numeric string" just means that it is a numeric value, stored inside a string variable.
I have provided two example that shows the different
first with a numeric string

```
$id =(string)42;
echo ($id);
echo '<br>';
echo ($id+1);
echo '<br>';
echo gettype($id);
echo '<br>';
echo gettype($id+1);
```

Out put will be lilke this

> 42
>
> 43
>
> string
>
> integer

and when the value of a variable be the integer

```
$id =intval('42');
echo ($id);
echo '<br>';
echo ($id+1);
echo '<br>';
echo gettype($id);
echo '<br>';
echo gettype($id+1);
```

and Out put will be this

> 42
>
> 43
>
> integer
>
> integer

Comment: Thank you for a support!

Answer (score 2):

```
$array['id'] = 2;
$id=intval($array['id']);
echo ($id+1);

gettype($id) ;
gettype($id+1);
```

The error is coming from your first line.

You should see an error in the first line the way you set your id but either way it's not an integer the way you try to set it. Check my code and let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Thank you for a support!